# Unity does not open scripts using vscode, even tho it is set as an external text editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

So becouse of my visual studio 2017 trial is about to end, i decided to switch to vs code and make a new project. The problem is that i cant open any scripts by double-clicking in that new project using vs code. Simply nothing happens. When i go to my older project and try to open scripts there using vscode everything works fine. When i try to create new projects the problem with scripts not opening persists.

Both of the projects run on the same unity version, and both of them have vscode set as an external script editor in the preferences. Task manager doesnt show anything related to vscode.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: please add the "already set as external text editor" in the body as well, its relevant information and should be together with the rest of the context to your question

Comment: It is there, in the second part "Both of the projects run on the same unity version, and both of them have vscode set as an external script editor in the preferences"

Comment: open by file extension fixes it for me (I had the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem where it opened up VS but not the exact script I was trying to open. I found out I had to 'reset argument' under "Edit--> Preferences --> External Tools" and just press reset argument.
Or just copy my line below:

"$(ProjectPath)" -g "$(File)":$(Line):$(Column)

[External tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T81MX.png)

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your external editor to VsCode.

Go to **Edit** -> **Preferences** -> **External tools**
Click on the External Script Editor and browse for vscode.

Comment: I have typed in my og post that this does not solve my problem. The external editor is already set to vscode.

Comment: Hmm missread that part. Your problem is more unique than i thought